# Radio Button Group in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a field of Boolean in Model named `Child_With_Bed` .

[image]

Now, I want radio button group in which yes = true and no = false. So when I select it `Child_With_Bed`'s value is set.

I tried below code but it is not getting bind with my model.

```
<tr>
  <th>
     <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Child_With_Bed)%>
  </th>
  <td>
     <%: Html.RadioButton("child", Model.Child_With_Bed)%> Yes 
     <%: Html.RadioButton("child", !Model.Child_With_Bed)%> No 
  </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to do this. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "Yes")%>
         Yes
        <% @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.item, "No")%>
          No
  <%  }%>
```

Comment: I am not getting How I implement it. I am not using razor and I have boolean field, how could I loop through it?

Comment: Just one question. Here Model will be class, So do I have to make a separate class for child_with_bed ?

Comment: i think child_with_bed  is field of your Model? yes?

Comment: yES. and it is of boolean type.

Comment: then you can use, `m=> m.child_with_bed`